# Flutter_google_places null check operator

Tags: flutter, google-places-api

In my Flutter application, I'm trying to implement flutter_google_places

When calling `PlacesAutocomplete.show`

I get this error:

> Null check operator used on a null value" #0
> PlacesAutocompleteState.doSearch
> (package:flutter_google_places/src/flutter_google_places.dart:436:28)

I call it this: `kGoogleApiKey` is provided as a string.

```
PlacesAutocomplete.show(
  context: context,
  apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
  mode: Mode.fullscreen, // Mode.overlay
  language: "en",
  components: [Component(Component.country, "pk")]
).then((value) => print(value))
```

Using:

```
flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.16
```

In Flutter 3.3.1

Comment: It seems to be related to this:
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_google_places/issues/203
I had to add 'types' and 'strictbounds' to the call parameters.
But now I don't have any results when searching and I'm not sure how to check if my parameters are correct (API key etc..). Calling 'onError' doesn't throw errors

Comment: Hi Doran, great that you could move forward in your problem. If you run into additional problems, you are better of creating a separate question for that (if you can't find a solution by other means). Comments are not meant for extending the scope of a question

Comment: Went out that I was using the wrong api key. Question answered. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_google_places/issues/164), you will need to provide more arguments to your function call. If they are not provided, the function body will still try to access these non-existing values and throw an exception while doing so.

```
Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
  offset: 0,
  radius: 1000,
  types: [],
  strictbounds: false,
  region: "ar",
  context: context,
  apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
  mode: Mode.overlay, // Mode.fullscreen
  language: "en",
  components: [Component(Component.country, "pk")]
);
```

Comment: It's not working with the below parameters too......


context: context,
        sessionToken: sessionToken,
        hint: "Address search",
        overlayBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        apiKey: "",

        mode: Mode.overlay,
        components: [
          Component(Component.country, "ca"),
        ],
        offset: 0,
        radius: 1000,
        types: [],
        strictbounds: false,
        region: "ca",